# trying to use tracerout in a shell script and i cant get it to display properly

Tags: traceroute

```
#!/bin/bash

host_name=A

echo -n " Enter a host name "
read host_name
total_hops=  traceroute $host_name | cut -d " " -f 1 | wc -l
read $total_hops
echo "The host $host_name is $total_hops away"
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183625/parsing-data-from-traceroute-command

Answer (score 0):

Two things don't make sense to me about your script: first, you don't need `read $total_hops` because you're already assigning it; second, if you just want to count the lines, you can just use `wc` without `cut`. But seem to be some extra lines in there that should not count as hops, so I would get the last line using `tail` and then use the `cut` to get the first column of that:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a host name "
read host_name
total_hops=`traceroute $host_name | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1 `
echo "The host $host_name is $total_hops hops away"
```

The output is:

```
> Enter a host name google.com 
> traceroute to google.com (216.58.216.46), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets 
> The host google.com is 12 hops away
```